# Logical error for prime number generator using while loops alone

Tags: python, for-loop, primes

Following is the code to generate prime nos:

```
to_num=int(raw_input("Enter till where u wish to generate prime nos > "))

i=2
flag="prime"
j=2
while i <= to_num:

 while j<i:

  if i%j == 0:
   flag="nprime"
   break
  else:
   flag="prime"


 if flag=="prime":
  print "%d is  prime"%i


  j+=1
 i+=1
```

However the result produced isnt as expected, e.g:

```
Enter till where u wish to generate prime nos > 10
2 is  prime
3 is  prime
4 is  prime
5 is  prime
6 is  prime
7 is  prime
8 is  prime
9 is  prime
10 is  prime
```

Could you please guide me as to where i am going wrong?

P.S: The desired results are obtained using `for` loop.

Comment: your code seems to work just fine: http://ideone.com/u1Ij7Q

Comment: this code produces the correct result and not what you posted.

Comment: Ohh !!!
My bad... posted the wrong code...  I'll edit the post ,,,

Comment: @abhisheknair why change the code if you already have the solution?

Comment: You need to reset `j = 2` at the beginning of the outer loop.

Comment: @poke I tried assigning j = 2 at the beginning of the inner loop..
In that case the execution does not go past "2 is prime" i.e the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loops looked like this:

```
for i in range(2, to_num+1):
    for j in range(2, i):
        …
```

But your while loops look like this:

```
i = 2
j = 2
while i <= to_num:
    while j < i:
        …
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

So you never reset `j` back to 2 after the loop completes. You should add a  `j = 2` at the beginning of the outer loop in order to make the while loops equivalent to the for loops:

```
i = 2
while i <= to_num:
    j = 2
    while j < i:
        …
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

Finally note, that you want to increment `j` in *every iteration*. In the code in your question, you have the `j += 1` as part of the `if flag=="prime":`, so it would only increment `j` for primes. Instead, you need to move the increment up into the while loop:

```
i = 2
while i <= to_num:
    j = 2
    while j < i:
        # the prime check here
        j += 1

    if flag == "prime":
        print "%d is  prime" % i

    i += 1
```

I would really suggest you to use a bigger indentation than *a single space* in order to see these issues yourself. They are hard to spot when everything is indented so similarly.

Comment: I tried assigning j = 2 at the beginning of the outer loop as explained.. In that case the execution does not go past "2 is prime" i.e the first line.

Comment: Thank You @poke .  That solved the doubt!
Will keep the indentation in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your inner flags and counters:

```
to_num=100

i=2
is_prime=False
j=2
while i <= to_num:
 is_prime=True // you need to reset your inner flags
 j=2 // set j to starting value
 while j<i:

  if i%j == 0:
   is_prime=False
   break

  j+=1

 if is_prime==True:
   print (i)

 i+=1
```

It's also better to use boolean flag, instead of string. It's more readable, and you don;t need to bother about the String.